# Match name with underscore following number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I have a file name like 'Doc 16_1.pdf' and i have to check that name exists or not with preg_match, if it is match the next number will be 'Doc 16_2.pdf'

```
'/(?:(?: \(_[\d]+\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/'
```

$name = 'Doc 16';

Im checking like

```
    return preg_replace_callback(
        /(?:(?: \(_[\d]+\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/,
        array($this, 'upcount_name_callback'),
        $name,
        1
    );
```

Incrementing like

```
protected function upcount_name_callback($matches) {
    print_r($matches);
    $index = isset($matches[1]) ? ((int)$matches[1]) + 1 : 1;        
    $ext = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';        
    $nm = '_'.$index.$ext;        
    return $nm;
}
```

I have tried the above preg_match but its not returning the matching results.

Can you please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `'~_\d+\.[^.]+$~'` will do?

Comment: What is the sample input, what is the desired output?

Comment: Can you give some examples? I'm not sure I got it correct

Comment: You are not using a `preg_match`, but `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: where do you have to check if it does really exists? If you are looking into a directory then simple answer is just `file_exists`

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320701/3832970) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Take this as a starting point.

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/^(.*)_(\d*)\.pdf$/", $filename, $output)) {
    $docname = $output[1];
    $num = (int)$output[2];
}
?>
```

e.g. http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lns

Answer (score 0):

You may increment the number using

```
preg_replace_callback('/_(\d+)(\.[^.]+)?$/', function($m) {
    return "_" . ($m[1]+1) . $m[2];
},$name);
```

**Details**

- `_` - an underscore
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$m[1]`): one or more digits
- `(\.[^.]+)?` - an optional group 2 (`$m[2]`):  a dot and 1 or more chars other than `.`
- `$` - end  of string.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/4Y5JW0):

```
$name = 'Doc 16_1.pdf';
echo preg_replace_callback('/_(\d+)(\.[^.]+)?$/', function($m) {
    return "_" . ($m[1]+1) . $m[2];
},$name);
```